# Как получить доступ к переменным контроллера в другом классе ? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть fxml файл, созданный через SceneBuilder. Там я ввожу номер лифтов, их вместимость, количество этажей и количество людей на этаже. Я считываю информацию в соответствующие переменные, объявленные в классе *WelcomeController*.

#### WelcomeController.java

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class WelcomeController {

    @FXML
    private TextField elevatorsTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField capacityTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField floorsTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField peopleTextField;
    @FXML
    private Button myButton;

    public int elevators, capacity, floors, people;

    public void start(ActionEvent push) {
        try {
            elevators = Integer.parseInt(elevatorsTextField.getText());
            capacity = Integer.parseInt(capacityTextField.getText());
            floors = Integer.parseInt(floorsTextField.getText());
            people = Integer.parseInt(peopleTextField.getText());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public int getElevators() {
        return this.elevators;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return this.capacity;
    }

    public int getFloors() {
        return this.floors;
    }

    public int getPeople() {
        return this.people;
    }

}
```

Мне нужно получить доступ к этим переменным в другом файле. Но обратиться к переменным этого класса даже через геттеры не получается. Пробовал сделать методы и переменные статичными, тоже не помогло, поскольку пока я ввожу данные в GUI, геттеры срабатывают и возвращают мне пустые значения.

#### Main.java

```
package sample;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        try {
            Parent welcome = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
            Scene welcomeScene = new Scene(welcome);
            stage.setScene(welcomeScene);
            stage.show();

            int num1, num2, num3, num4;
            // ???

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте объект, к которому будут иметь доступ оба контроллера. Например, `DomRepository`, Пусть для простоты, он будет синглтоном. В обоих контроллерах, в блоке с полями получите экземпляр этого объекта. И наполняйте структуру с лифтами и людьми в этом объекте. Что-то вроде `DomRepository.getInstance().getEntrance(5).setElevators(Integer.parseInt(elevatorsTextField.getText()));`
`DomRepository.getInstance().getEntrance(5).getElevators()`. Что бы было более правильно, вместо синглтонов прочитайте про Dependency Injection.